# Turn a data type into a String for display without `show`

Tags: haskell

This question has me absolutely puzzled. The goal is to take a specific data type and use it to create a string. The data type is:

```
data Math = Val Int
           | Add Math Math
           | Sub Math Math
           | Mult Math Math
           | Div Math Math
    deriving Show
```

This example:

```
ex1 :: Math
ex1 = Add1 (Val1 2) (Val1 3)
```

should output `"2 + 3"` with the correct code.

I wrote the following code and realized I was having two issues:

```
show :: Math -> String
show (Val n)        = show n
show (Add e1 e2)    = show e1 ++ " + " ++ show e2
show (Sub e1 e2)    = show e1 ++ " - " ++ show e2
show (Mult e1 e2)   = show e1 ++ " * " ++ show e2
show (Div e1 e2)    = show e1 ++ " / " ++ show e2
```

The curve ball is that the function MUST be named `show`, as it is - so calling `show` from Prelude won't work. My first thought it to create a helper that turns every value into a literal but, again, I have no idea how to do that without `show` for a data type. I legitimately have no idea what direction to head in.

Comment: I suspect your code is actually ok as-is. The naming requirement is, unfortunately, obscuring things. Try something: Add in the function `showInt :: Int -> String; showInt = Prelude.show` and then rewrite your `show` so that it is named `myShow` instead and use `showInt`. Also, remove `deriving Show` from your `data` definition. I think doing this could help clarify things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there! To keep `show` from the Prelude from interfering, add

```hs
import Prelude hiding (show)
```

to the top of your file.

But then, you'll need access to Prelude's `show` after all, so that you can show the `Int` inside your `Val`. So *also* add this:

```hs
import qualified Prelude (show)
```

With those two lines, you can write:

```hs
show :: Math -> String
show (Val n)        = Prelude.show n
show (Add e1 e2)    = show e1 ++ " + " ++ show e2
show (Sub e1 e2)    = show e1 ++ " - " ++ show e2
show (Mult e1 e2)   = show e1 ++ " * " ++ show e2
show (Div e1 e2)    = show e1 ++ " / " ++ show e2
```

and you should have what you want.

---

Alternatively, if you want to be implementing `Show` the class instead of a standalone, identically (and confusingly) named `show` function, the code you have for `show` works as-is. You just need to put it inside an instance definition, like this:

```hs
instance Show Math where
    show (Val n)        = show n
    -- etc...
```

Comment: That's great but there's no way that's an allowable answer for this; he wants us to figure out a way to show them with...something. A function helper? I have no idea. Is this legitimately the only way to display it? Usually we're not allowed to import something unless specified.

Comment: Can you go into more detail about these constraints you're working under? How much of this code is yours to modify and how much is the instructor's?

Comment: `show :: Math -> String` is the teachers, with: write a function that displays a String of the type. Really, I can use some library calls but I know that importing something to go around his question won't be what he wants.

Comment: In the base library, the only way to get the string representation of an `Int` is to call `show` from Prelude, one way or another.

Comment: Is it possible that you're supposed to be implementing the `Show` *class* by hand instead of letting GHC do it with `deriving Show`? That would also involve implementing a `show :: Math -> String`, just inside an instance definition.

Comment: I did add `deriving Show` to the data type myself but I could define it with the function myself instead of using it in the data type?

Comment: @Francis In this answer, the only place that the builtin `show` is being is the very first line of the `show` definition (`show (Val n) = ...`) and it is only being used to `show` an `Int`. The other `show` calls are recursive calls to the newly defined `show`. I imagine that would be allowed.

Comment: If you aren't permitted to fiddle with imports in any way, then defining an instance of `Show` by hand (instead of adding `deriving Show`) is the only solution that makes sense to me (see edited answer). It's also what anyone would do in real life in most normal circumstances, and is much less confusing to read—assuming you've been taught how to think about classes and instances in Haskell.

Comment: I just want to thank you so much. The answer was literally staring me in the face and you went above and beyond! From the bottom of my heart, you saved me so much effort - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can either disable the `show` method defined by `Show`:

```
import Prelude hiding (show)
```

or you can explicitly refer to `show` defined in your module. Assuming it is defined in `Main`,

```
main = putStrLn $ Main.show (Val 3)
```

Comment: Can you explain your second answer a bit? It isn't written in main, the code is exactly as it looks.

Comment: The point is that you need a qualified name to distinguish *your* `show` function from the method provided by the Prelude via the `Show` class. It might not be `Main`, and you might need to actually *define* a module so that there is a qualified name to use.